# In C, how do we force the last argument in a varargs function to be a terminating null?

Tags: c, function, variadic-functions, default-arguments

In C++, we might write something like this:

```
#include <cassert.h>
#include <cstdio.h>
#include <cstdarg.h>

void func(..., short end = 0) {

   // prevent caller from overriding default value with something other than null 
   assert(end == 0);

   va_list args;  

   short x;
   x = va_arg(args, short); 

   while (x != 0) {
       printf("%d", va_arg(args, short));
   }

   va_end(list);

   return;
}
```

However, C does not support default function arguments. Is there someway that I can force `func` to have a trailing null character at the end of its argument list? Is there some way to do it without having the programmer explicitly pass the terminating null into to the function?

We do not want to see calls like the following:

```
int   x = 5;
float y = 6.4;
func(x, y, 0);
```

We just want `func(x, y);`.

Is it possible to write a macro that would convert text like

`func(x, y);`

into the call:

`func(x, y, 0);`?

Is there some way to do this without a macro?

Comment: If you want to fix a function argument to some constant value, then perhaps it shouldn't be a parameter in the first place.

Comment: Short answer -> you can't. Long answer -> you still can't.

Comment: Um, that is not valid C++ either.

Answer (score 8):

You can't force a varargs function to have a specific "last" value in C.

There needs to be something within the argument list that tells the function how many arguments there are.  A few examples from the standard library:

- `printf`: the format string tells the function how many arguments and what their types are.
- `execl`: takes a number of `const char *` arguments, the last of which must be `NULL`.

So having a "flag" argument as the last when calling a varargs function is a known programming paradigm in C.  It's not something you need to cover up.

---

That being said, you can use a macro to do what you want:

```
#define FUNC(...) func(__VA_ARGS__, 0)
```

The `...` in the macro argument list captures all arguments, and the `__VA_ARGS__` macro represents those arguments.

Then you can define `func` like this:

```
void func(short first, ...)
```

And call it via the macro like this

```
FUNC(x, y);
```

Comment: You don't need to define a macro with a different name. If a macro expands to itself then it stops expanding. If you call it func in your example then it will be transparent to the user of the function.

Answer (score 3):

That is not how C varargs are intended to be used, so it be hard to get them to work that way.  There is supposed to be a mandatory leading argument from which you can deduce the number and types of the following arguments.  The format string fills this role for the printf family of functions.  You could take an integer for the number of parameters and encode the type in the function name.

```
funcs(int num, ...); // s for short
```

That won't provide any type enforcement though.  The compiler will still allow non-shorts to be passed.  There is no way to enforce types through the vararg.  At this point you might as well use the classic array and count idiom.

```
funcs(int num, short const*);
```

Answer (score 0):

`#define func(x,y,z) func(x,y)` should work as a macro, however what you want (a different number of arguments with a same function name) is not possible in C.
You could also have a function where you pass an array containing the argument and the number of arguments as an integer, then you can do different things depending on how many arguments were given.

Comment: The question is about the use of varargs.

Comment: Then why can I read: "Is it possible to write a macro that would convert text like [...]"? The question seems to be more about polymorphism expression in C than about varargs.

Comment: See the title of the post